# How to view the data received by pushgetway on prometheus

Tags: python, prometheus

I have configured pushgetway in prometheus.yml and received the data in localhost:9091. However, I do not see the data information received by pushgetway in localhost:9090. I can only see the pushgetway configuration information. How can I achieve this?

[This is the configuration of pushgetway for prometheus settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPmPj.jpg)

Comment: Please provide us with some code so we can help you out.

Comment: pushgetway insert data:

cat <<EOF | curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/job_file
some_table1{label="test",scheme="http",src_ip="192.168.33.85",dst_ip="192.168.33.86"} 44
some_table2{lable1="other"} 123
another_table{lable1="aaa"} 234.12
EOF

Comment: @HimanshuBansal

Comment: I solved this problem. Is the metrics of the operation wrong